# React-Bootstrap <SSRProvider> is a Client Component?

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, react-bootstrap, createcontext

## The Problem

#### `<SSRProvider>`

React-Bootstrap's `<SSRProvider>`'s dependency (node_modules/@react-aria/ssr/dist/main.js (46:99)) uses `createContext`. This means that the server side rendering is either a joke or I am doing something wrong.

## My Code

I am using Next.js 13.5.4 with react-bootstrap.

#### app/layout.tsx

```
import Navigation from '@/components/Navigation/Navigation';
import SSRProvider from 'react-bootstrap/SSRProvider';
import './globals.scss';

export const metadata = {
  title: 'OpenPoultry',
  description: 'For straightforward note taking'
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
     <SSRProvider>
      <html lang="en">
        <body>
          <Navigation />
          {children}
        </body>
      </html>
    </SSRProvider>
  )
}
```

#### app/components/Navigation/Navigation.jsx

```
"use client"
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import NavDropdown from 'react-bootstrap/NavDropdown';
import Link from 'next/link';

function Navigation() {
  return (
    <Navbar expand="lg" className="bg-body-tertiary">
      <Container>
        <Link href="#home" passHref><Navbar.Brand>React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand></Link>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="me-auto">
            <Link href="#home" passHref><Nav.Link as="span">Home</Nav.Link></Link>
            <Link href="#link" passHref><Nav.Link as="span">Link</Nav.Link></Link>
            <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
              <Link href="#action/3.1" passHref><NavDropdown.Item  as="span">Action</NavDropdown.Item></Link>
              <Link href="#action/3.2" passHref><NavDropdown.Item as="span">
                Another action
              </NavDropdown.Item></Link>
              <Link href="#action/3.3" passHref><NavDropdown.Item as="span">Something</NavDropdown.Item></Link>
              <NavDropdown.Divider />
              <Link href="#action/3.4" passHref={true}><NavDropdown.Item as="span">
                Separated link
              </NavDropdown.Item></Link>
            </NavDropdown>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
}

export default Navigation;
```